# Store subcollection data in Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem on to add a subcollection "Diary" under collection "Users". How to make it so that one user can have several diary?

Here's Java codes:

```
check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FirebaseUser user = fAuth.getCurrentUser();
            String uid = user.getUid();
            DocumentReference df = fStore.collection("Diary").document(user.getUid());
            Map<String, Object> diaryInfo = new HashMap<>();
            diaryInfo.put("Symptom", symptom.getEditText().getText().toString());
            diaryInfo.put("UID", uid);
            diaryInfo.put("Note", note.getEditText().getText().toString());
            diaryInfo.put("Date", dateButton.getText().toString());

            SimpleDateFormat tf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
            String currentTime = tf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            time.setText(currentTime);
            diaryInfo.put("Time",time.getText().toString());

            feeling = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            diaryInfo.put("Feeling", feeling);

            df.set(diaryInfo).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Object o) {
                    Toast.makeText(add_diary_user.this, "Data successfully stored", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(add_diary_user.this, diary_user.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(add_diary_user.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Database structure:
[image]

[image]

Comment: So to understand better, you need to have a "Diary" sub-collection under the user ID document, right?

Comment: yes, so that it can specific which diary to be stored in which user

Comment: Oh, you already got a good answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place your subcollection inside the corresponding document of your parent collection:

```
// Create a reference to a new 'Diary' document at Users/user_id/Diary/doc_id
// with an auto-generated document id
DocumentReference df = fStore.collection("Users").document(user.getUid()).collection("Diary").document();
```

When you need to retrieve the diaries, query the individual user's Diary collection:

```
fStore.collection("Users").document(user.getUid()).collection("Diary")
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // Do something with your retrieved documents
            }
        }
    }
```